# Conditional Expectation | Independent sigma-fields and uniqueness theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-explanation, conditional-expectation

I have problems in understanding a small part in a proof, which is, however, a really important part.

**Given:**

- $X,Y,Z$ are random variables such that $\sigma(X,Y)$ and $\sigma(Z)$ are independent
- $h: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ is a Borel function which we assume to be bounded
- **(*)** By the uniqueness theorem of probability measures, we know that for all $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, $\mathbb{E}[h(X)\mathbb{I}_{\{(Y,Z)\in A\}}] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[h(X)\mid Y]\mathbb{I}_{\{(Y,Z)\in A\}}] $ holds

**What the proof states** (not relevant for the question, only if someone is interested :-) ):

$\mathbb{P}$ a. s. $\mathbb{E}[h(X)\mid\sigma(Y,Z)] = \mathbb{E}[h(X)\mid Y]$

**My question:**

After **(*)**, it is stated that by the uniqueness of the conditional expectation$^1$,
$$\mathbb{E}[h(X)\mid\sigma(Y,Z)] = \mathbb{E}[h(X)\mid Y] \hspace{2cm} \tag 1$$
is implied $\mathbb{P}$ a.s..
I don't understand where the equation (1) comes from...

**My attempt of explanation:**

If I look at **(*)** and consider the uniqueness theorem of conditional expectation, I would say that
$$\mathbb{E}[h(X)\mid Y] \mbox{ is a version of the conditional expectation of }  h(X) \hspace{2cm}   \tag 2$$
$\mathbb{P}$ a.s.. Now, I try to come from $(2)$ to $(1).$ But that does not really work. So, I think I miss something?

**A further question (not so important)**

Does someone may have an intuitive explanation about why $h$ maps to $\mathbb{R}^+$ and not $\mathbb{R}$? I don't see why this general case should not hold. (But this is not my main worry :-) )

Thanks a million in advance for your help!

$^1$The uniqueness theorem of conditional expectations sates that if **(*)** holds for two random variables $X_0$ and $\tilde X_0$, then $X_0$ = $\tilde X_0$ $\mathbb{P}$ a.s.

Comment: $h(X)$ is not the same as its conditional expectation given $Y$. So your equation 2 is incorrect.

Comment: I thought that this is implied by the uniqueness theorem? If (*) holds for two random variables (which I considered as h(X) and the conditional expectation), then those are the same?

Comment: Instead, you want to show that $E[h(X)|Y]$ is a valid version of $E[h(X)|Y,Z]$.

Comment: Let $h(X)=X$ and let $Y=Z=0$. Then you are claiming $X$ is almost surely equal to its expectation, which cannot be true in general.

Comment: Thank you! I understand now why my assumption is wrong. But nevertheless, I don't see how (1) follows from (*)...

Comment: You can use the required properties of a conditional expectation $E[h(X)|Y,Z]$, show that $E[h(X)|Y]$ satisfies it. By the way , not that it seems to matter here, but what precisely do you mean by “the uniqueness theorem”?

Comment: (There isn’t much to show as equation * is essentially it already)

Comment: @Michael I added a foot note to the questions where I stated the uniqueness theorem. The uniqueness theorem was the reason why I thought that h(X)=E[h(X)∣Y]. ( So I choose $X_0 =h(X)$ and $\tilde X_0 = E[h(X)∣Y]$. Could you maybe describe it in greater detail why from ( * ) the claim follows? I am really despaired of this since I simply don't see how the conditional expectation follows from ( * )... Thanks a million in advance!

Comment: @Michael I also adjusted the "My interpretation" part in the question... However, I am still stuck...

Comment: Thanks for letting me know what you meant by the uniqueness theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Definitions

- A version of $E[h(X)|Y]$ is a random variable of the form $g(Y)$ (for some function $g$) that satisfies
  $$ E[h(X)1_{\{Y \in A\}}] = E[g(Y)1_{\{Y \in A\}}] \quad \forall A \in B(\mathbb{R})$$
- A version of $E[h(X)|Y, Z]$ is a random variable of the form $r(Y,Z)$ (for some function $r$) that satisfies
  $$ E[h(X)1_{\{(Y,Z) \in B\}}] = E[r(Y,Z)1_{\{(Y,Z) \in B\}}] \quad \forall B \in B(\mathbb{R}^2)$$

#### The given problem

Now I *think* your problem is this:  You are told $E[h(X)|Y]$ is a particular version of the conditional expectation of $h(X)$ given $Y$ (so you can call it $g(Y)$ for some function $g$ if you want, that is, $g(Y)=E[h(X)|Y]$). You are also told $E[h(X)|Y]$ satisfies an additional property called Property *:

\begin{align}
&\mbox{Property *}: \\
&E[h(X)1_{\{(Y,Z) \in B\}}] = E\left[\underbrace{E[h(X)|Y]}_{g(Y)}1_{\{(Y,Z) \in B\}}\right] \quad \forall B \in B(\mathbb{R}^2)
\end{align}

Finally, from this property, you are being asked to verify that your random variable $g(Y)$ is *also* a version of $E[h(X)|Y,Z]$.

#### Solution

What do we need to show to conclude that $g(Y)$ is a version of $E[h(X)|Y,Z]$?   Well, we would need to show $g(Y)$ is a pure function of $(Y,Z)$ (which it is, since it is in fact a pure function of $Y$ alone) and
$$ E[h(X)1_{\{(Y,Z) \in B\}}] = E[g(Y)1_{\{(Y,Z)\in B\}}] \quad \forall B \in B(\mathbb{R}^2)$$
**But the given Property * itself is the same as this equation that we need to show**.  So this problem really just asks to verify that property * immediately implies that $g(Y)$ is a version of $E[h(X)|Y,Z]$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was totally confused although it was "only" verifying the definition closely. Now, it is clear to me :-)

Comment: You are welcome.  Note that I did not say "by the uniqueness theorem" anywhere because we never needed it.  We were only being asked to verify that a given function satisfied certain requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured it out. Thanks for the thought provoking impulses @Michael.

So, as mentioned in the question, we know that $\mathbb{E}[h(X)\mid Y]$ is a version of the conditional expectation of $h(X) $.

However, we also know that for all

$$A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), \quad\mathbb{E}[h(X)\mathbb{I}_{\{(Y,Z)\in A\}}] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[h(X)\mid \sigma(Y,Z)]\mathbb{I}_{\{(Y,Z)\in A\}}] $$

simply by definition of the conditional expectation.

Now, the uniqueness theorem for conditional expectation yields that

$\mathbb{P}$ a. s. $\mathbb{E}[h(X)\mid\sigma(Y,Z)] = \mathbb{E}[h(X)\mid Y]$

since the conditional expectation of $h(X)$ is unique.

Would be great if one could leave a short comment if I did not miss anything in the answer :-)

Comment: I do not follow.  You start with $E[h(X)|Y]$, then you state a fact for $E[h(X)|Y, Z]$.  At no point do you mention the equation (*) from your question, which I thought you were supposed to use.  I do not know where the "Now the uniqueness theorem" comes in to your argument.  I think you are saying "by the uniqueness theorem" too much.